# ReactJS component passing data back to parent component not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, reactjs

I am working on a ReactJS component that is rendering a Google map from the Google Maps Javascript API. On the map I am dynamically placing markers that is showing different distributor locations. Right now the mock data is coming from an array of distributors with different informations and is being iterated by a loop. When a marker is clicked I have the InfoWindow showing the distributors details. Now in this InfoWindow I have a button that allows the customer to select this distributor.

The GoogleMap component is owned by the ChooseDistributor component. When the button is clicked I want an ID (which is right now a string with the name of the distributor) to be sent back to the ChooseDistributor component by a callback function.

The problem is that I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callbackParent' of undefined` when I click the button. This might be a scope issue since `this` is not referring to the GoogleMap component itself while I am in the loop(?).

I have then tried to create a variable `callbackParent` outside of the loop which contains `this.props.callbackParent` that should link back to the receiving function in the ChooseDistributor component. I am then calling this variable on the button onclick. This does not work either as I am getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: callbackParent is not defined`.

I would appreciate if anyone has a possible solution to this problem. Am I missing something or is it a plain syntactical error? Thanks in advance.

Below is my code.

ChooseDistributor component

```
var ChooseDistributor = React.createClass({
    getSelectedDistributor: function(company){
        alert(company);
    },

    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Header headerClass="title" title="Choose distributor"/>
                <div className="fillViewPort">
                    <GoogleMap enableIwSelectButton={true} callbackParent={this.getSelectedDistributor}/>
                </div>
                <NavBar />
            </div>

        );
    }
})
module.exports = ChooseDistributor;
```

GoogleMap component:

```
var GoogleMap = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            // LOCATIONS STATE SHOULD GET DATA FROM STORE
            locations: [
                // ARRAY VALUES: [0]=LAT, [1]=LNG, [2]=COMPANY, [3]=ADDRESS, [4]=CITY, [5]=WEBSITE, [6]=PHONE, [7]=EMAIL
                [55.628353, 12.388910, 'Distributor One', 'First street 11', '1111 Copenhagen', 'www.company.com', '+4512345678', 'distributor@company.dk'],
                [55.623321, 12.388438, 'Distributor Two', 'Second street 22', '2222 Copenhagen', 'www.company.com', '+4512345678', 'distributor@company.dk'],
                [55.670710, 12.389256, 'Distributor Three', 'Third street 33', '3333 Copenhagen', 'www.company.com', '+4512345678', 'distributor@company.dk'],
                [55.581179, 12.295583, 'Distributor Four', 'Fourth street 44', '4444 Copenhagen', 'www.company.com', '+4512345678', 'distributor@company.dk'],
                [55.647296, 12.284211, 'Distributor Five', 'Fifth street 55', '5555 Copenhagen', 'www.company.com', '+4512345678', 'distributor@company.dk']
            ]
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        var locations = this.state.locations;
        var enableIwSelectButton = this.props.enableIwSelectButton;
        var callbackParent = this.props.callbackParent;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
            zoom: 11,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][0], locations[0][1]), // CENTER PROPERTY SHOULD GET COORDINATES OF THE DEVICE CURRENT LOCATION IF PERMITTED.
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        // PLACE MARKER ON MAP FOR EACH DISTRIBUTOR POSITION IN ARRAY.
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
                map: map
            });
            // ADD INFOWINDOW WITH DISTRIBUTOR DETAILS TO EACH MARKER.
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {

                    infoWindow.setContent('<p class="iwTitle">' + locations[i][2] + '</p>'+
                        '<p class="iwText">' + locations[i][3] + '<br>' +
                        locations[i][4] + '<br>' +
                        '<a href="http://' + locations[i][5] + '">' + locations[i][5] + '</a></p>' +
                        '<p class="iwText"><i class="fa fa-phone iwIcons"></i>' + locations[i][6] + '<br>' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-envelope iwIcons"></i><a href="mailto:"' + locations[i][7] + '>'  + locations[i][7] + '</a></p>' +
                        (enableIwSelectButton ? '<button type="button" class="iwButton" onclick={this.props.callbackParent(locations[i][3])}><p>Select Distributor</p></button>' : ''));
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
          <div id="googleMap" className="size-100-pct" />
        );
    }
})

module.exports = GoogleMap;
```

UPDATE:
Thanks to @Radio- my problem was solved. The solution was to give each button an Id and then fetch the button afterwards by that Id and add an eventlistener to it like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {

                    infoWindow.setContent('<p class="iwTitle">' + locations[i][2] + '</p>'+
                        '<p class="iwText">' + locations[i][3] + '<br>' +
                        locations[i][4] + '<br>' +
                        '<a href="http://' + locations[i][5] + '">' + locations[i][5] + '</a></p>' +
                        '<p class="iwText"><i class="fa fa-phone iwIcons"></i>' + locations[i][6] + '<br>' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-envelope iwIcons"></i><a href="mailto:"' + locations[i][7] + '>'  + locations[i][7] + '</a></p>' +
                        (enableIwSelectButton ? '<button type="button" id="btnSelect' + i + '" class="iwButton"><p>Select Distributor</p></button>' : ''));
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    var el = document.getElementById("btnSelect" + i);
                    el.addEventListener("click", function(){callbackParent(locations[i][2])});
                }
            })(marker, i));
```

Comment: Have you tried bind this to the parent component ?
`<GoogleMap enableIwSelectButton={true} callbackParent={this.getSelectedDistributor.bind(this)}/>`

Comment: @somallg Yes I tried that. Not working either. It is giving a ´Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button in the InfoWindow isn't a React component. It's raw html, possibly parsed by `setContent`. So, the button's 'onclick' attribute is going to try to execute a function in the global namespace. It doesn't have any awareness of how it was created, and neither `callbackParent` nor `this.props.callbackParent` nor `locations[i][3]` is in the global namespace for it to reference.

You might be able to use regular DOM manipulation in `componentDidMount` to add the event listener.

```
infoWindow.setContent(... '<button type="button" class="iwButton"><p>Select Distributor</p></button>' : ''));
infoWindow.open(map, marker);

var el = document.getElementsByClassName("iwButton");
el.addEventListener("click", function() { callbackParent(locations[i][3]) });
```

Comment: This really did it. Though I used getElementById and gave each button an Id with the value of "btnSelect" + i (the counter in the loop). Thank you so much for your help @Radio-.

Answer (score 0):

'`this`' inside `callback` method refers to callback itself. So you can't access '`this`' inside callback function to refer outer scope.

try ES6 syntax:

```
 myFn:()=>{
this.props.any();
}
```

or,

```
var self = this.
myFn:function(){
  self.props.any();
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. How/where would you implement this?